# JavaScript prompt in Python

Tags: javascript, python, prompt

How can I replicate a JS prompt in Python? I've been trying to do this -- go through a course on one programming language and replicate the code in another language (the only two I'm very good at are JavaScript and Python, so those are the two I've been working with). I looked around on Google and on StackOverflow, but I haven't really found anything that answers the question that I have.

I want to replicate this:

```
var candy = prompt("What's your favorite candy?", 
"Type your favorite candy here.");
```

in Python, but make it as Pythonic as possible and if at all possible not have to import anything, ESPECIALLY not Tkinter.

JavaScript:

```
var candy = prompt("What's your favorite candy?", 
"Type your favorite candy here.");

switch(candy) 
{
case 'licorice':
    console.log("Gross!");
    break;
case 'gum':
    console.log("I like gum.");
    break;
case 'beets':
    console.log("...Is that even a candy?");
    break;
default:
    console.log("Please tell us your favorite candy");
}
```

Python - throws `EOFError` on line 1 in Sublime (?); works in Terminal. This means that there must be something wrong. I was using `if`/`elif`/`else` statements, `print`, and `break`.

I could be messing that up as well. Beginner mistakes and whatnot.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't really a way to replicate the JavaScript prompt in Python. The only way to get any kind of GUI is to use Tkinter or something similar. As Oscar said though you can use:

```
var candy = raw_input("What's Your Favorite Candy?")
```

This will give the user a text prompt on screen, not a pop-up type of prompt like in JavaScript.